# EditText variable is not assigning in another class

Tags: java, android, oop

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    TextView t = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView3);
    EditText e1 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1);
    EditText e2 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText2);
}

private void person() {
    String name = e1.getText();
    String phone = e2.getText();
}
```

Here why can't i access `e1` and `e2` in person class? error; `e1` and `e2` can't be resolved.

Comment: where is this other class? Does not look like valid java code to me

Comment: Sorry its method, not class..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well:

- `person` is **not** a [class](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/classes.html), is a [method](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/methods.html)!
- You cannot access `e1` and `e2` because they are local [variables](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/variables.html) of `onCreate` method

You should move `e1` and `e2` as fields of the class.

So it will be

```
// e1 and e2 are not anymore inside any method, so they will be fields of the class
EditText e1; 
EditText e2;

protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    TextView t = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView3);
    e1 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1);
    e2 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText2);
}

// person method can use them without problems
private void person()
{
    String name = e1.getText();
    String phone = e2.getText();
}
```

Comment: well, in your code `person()` is still a method, but looks like he was attempting to create an inner class

Comment: @donfuxx i'm pretty sure he is going to confuse the two things, that's why i linked the doc.

Comment: currently the persons() method seems to be pretty useless though